# Access JIRA over the internet (remotely) hosted by ec2 aws (windows server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, jira, windows-server-2008-r2

I have problem in accessing JIRA remotely.

My EC2 Micro Instance Setup:
Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server Express and IIS

I can see jira locally at

```
http://localhost:8080/jira, but cannot see remotely from any of these links: 
http://domain.com:8080/jira  
http://elasticIP:8080/jira  
http://awsPublicDNS:8080/jira
http://domain/jira  
http://elasticIP/jira  
http://awsPublicDNS/jira
```

port 8080 is open and I have no problem on these.

Would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: can you suggest me about how to install jira in aws(amazon) ec2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if Windows Firewall is enabled.